# Why do I get "AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute" using Tkinter? Where did the None value come from?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've created this simple GUI:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def grabText(event):
    print(entryBox.get())    

entryBox = Entry(root, width=60).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

grabBtn = Button(root, text="Grab")
grabBtn.grid(row=8, column=1)
grabBtn.bind('<Button-1>', grabText)

root.mainloop()
```

When I click on the `Grab` button, an error occurs:

```
C:\Python> python.exe myFiles\testBed.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1403, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "myFiles\testBed.py", line 10, in grabText
    if entryBox.get().strip()=="":
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Why is `entryBox` set to `None`?

---

<sub>See also [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252) for the general case.</sub>

Comment: TODO: make a **fully general** canonical explaining built-in and library methods that return `None`, and the design decision behind that (command-query separation). There are many of them, but it is the **same problem** every time. That covers the other aspect of this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252 covers understanding the error message.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The `grid`, `pack` and `place` functions of the `Entry` object and of all other widgets returns `None`. In python when you do `a().b()`, the result of the expression is whatever `b()` returns, therefore `Entry(...).grid(...)` will return `None`.

You should split that on to two lines like this:

```
entryBox = Entry(root, width=60)
entryBox.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

That way you get your `Entry` reference stored in `entryBox` and it's laid out like you expect. This has a bonus side effect of making your layout easier to understand and maintain if you collect all of your `grid` and/or `pack` statements in blocks.

Comment: So single line coding is not just syntactical, it also has semantic ramifications which is very unexpected.

Comment: @user7420124, not really. The difference is what you assign to `entryBox`: in one case it's what `Entry()` returns, in another it's what `grid()` returns.

Comment: If we want adding a final button like this: tkinter.Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda: [print(selection), root.destroy()]).pack() pack is require to add it but is not compatible with grid, how to deal that?

Comment: It's only unexpected if you pay no attention to what a method returns. `a.b.c` simply is not the same as `a.b`, then `a.c`.

Answer (score 17):

Change this line:

```
entryBox=Entry(root,width=60).grid(row=2, column=1,sticky=W)
```

into these two lines:

```
entryBox=Entry(root,width=60)
entryBox.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky=W)
```

Just as you already correctly do for `grabBtn`!

Answer (score 6):

Alternative solution for `Python3.8+` versions that allows to put all of this in one line using the [`walrus operator`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```py
(entryBox := Entry(root, width=60)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Now `entryBox` will refer to the `Entry` widget and also get packed.

For characters per line management I can suggest something like this:

```py
(var := Button(
    text='fine', command=some_func, width=20, height=15, activebackground='grey'
)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=0, rowspan=0, sticky='news')
```

But at that point might as well just do this "normally" (as suggested by other answers)

Sources:

- [PEP 572 -- Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)
- [IMO great video explanation about `walrus operator`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN2TTiGpDvM)

Answer (score 3):

For `entryBox.get()` to access `get()` method you need **Entry** object but `Entry(root, width=60).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)` returns None.

`entryBox = Entry(root, width=60)` creates a new Entry Object.

Moreover, you won't need
`entryBox = entryBox.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)` as it will rewrite `entryBox` with None

---

Just replace `entryBox = entryBox.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)`
with

```
entryBox = Entry(root, width=60)
entryBox.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of the accepted answer, but 11 years later?